# refresh information on page frequently

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring and MVC, but I have one problem to solve. I dont know what is a correct approach in this case.

I have class:

```
public class RandomNumbers
extends TimerTask

{ 
private Random random;
private int actualNumber;

public RandomNumbers(  )
{    
    this.random = new Random();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    actualNumber =
        random.nextInt( 100 );        
    System.out.println( actualNumber );
}

public int getActualNumber()
{
return actualNumber;
}
}
```

And thats works fine. I created new bean from this class and scheduled task. Eg. every 2s run() is executed and new acutalNumber is generated. Inside controller I've added:

```
model.addAttribute( "actualNumber", randomNumbers.getActualNumber() );
```

And thats works, I have on my jsp page printed first value of actualNumber.

The problem is that: even new number is generated (sysout works) information on page aren't refreshed. 
How should I receive new values from randomNumbers bean? e.g I would like to get new information when 'actualNumber' changed or every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time a user is seening the output from your JSP page, they are simply seeing HTML that was generated from the page. To make it dynamic, the browser must "know" to go get a new value.

For example, you could have some javascript on your page, which constantly refreshes the whole page. You could do something like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function timedRefresh() {   
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);",2000); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
...
```

Your next issue will be: how to get the updated value? Your back-ground process could simply keep updating the new value into a session-variable. The page can then consistently get the value from that session variable.

This might raise more questions, but I hope it starts you down the right path.

Comment: many thanks for answer. Script works.

No I have to challenge with session-variable. It's not so easy. 
I've added to jsp page:
    <%@ page session="true"%>
and annotation to controller:
    @SessionAttributes
but still value are not updated.
Should I declare in different way RandomNumbers bean? Or I missed something?

Comment: Ok, everything works fine now :) I had one mistake in code :(
once more Thanks for help

Comment: Mark it as answer if its helpful .